# docker python can't find address postgres

Tags: python, django, database, postgresql, docker

I run a container with postgresql and after that I run a container with python (Django). I am trying to connect to the database and in some cases I get an error.
This error happen after deleting compose project and trying to create that in 50% cases.If restart the backend container separately, then everything works fine.
This is my first time working with a docker, I hope for your help and possible tips :)

django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
Is the server running on host "postgres" (192.168.128.2) and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

settings.py

```
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
    'NAME': "postgres",
    'USER': "postgres",
    'PASSWORD': "postgres",
    'HOST': "postgres",
    'PORT': "5432",
}
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.8"
 services:
  postgres:
   image: postgres:15-alpine
   restart: always
   environment:
     POSTGRES_USER: postgres
     POSTGRES_DB: postgres
     POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
   volumes:
     - ./postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/
   ports:
     - "5432:5432"

 adminer:
   image: adminer
   restart: always
   links:
     - postgres
   ports:
     - "8080:8080"

 backend:
   links:
     - postgres
     - adminer
   build: ./settings/
   command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
   ports:
     - "8000:8000"
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.8.16-buster

WORKDIR /settings

COPY . .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Comment: Please write the error message here and do not use an image. Follow https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: can you share your compose file and docker files as well as the settings of DB, please?

Comment: Added files for more details